# window.location.replace() not working after success if condition using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

controller: Test/send_mail_account()

```
public function send_mail_account() 
{
    $usertype = $this->session->userdata("usertype");
    $loginuserID = $this->session->userdata("loginuserID");
    $adminID = $this->session->userdata("adminID");
    $email = $this->session->userdata("email");
    $username = $this->session->userdata("username");
    if($usertype == "Accountant") 
    {

        $totalData = $this->invoice_m->get_order_by_student_by_join_Count($adminID);
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;
        $data['posts'] = $this->invoice_m->make_datatables($adminID);

        $this->load->library('email');
        $config=array(
        'charset'=>'utf-8',
        'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
        'mailtype' => 'html'
        );

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $html = $this->load->view('emailTemplates/feeupdation/feeupdationaccountant', $data , true);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->from($email, $username);
        $this->email->to('xyz@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject("Student Account List");
        $this->email->message($html);
        $this->email->send();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->data["subview"] = "error";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}
```

view:

```
<script>
    function checkDate() {
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(date.getDay());
        console.log(date.getHours());
        console.log(date.getMinutes());
        console.log(date.getSeconds());
        if(date.getDay() === 3 && date.getHours() ===13 && date.getMinutes() === 33 && date.getSeconds() === 1) {
            window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/send_mail_account");
        }
    }

    var dateLoop = setInterval(function() {
        checkDate();
    },5000);
</script>
```

In this code I have a function i.e. `send_mail_account` where I want when my script run then it redirect me on controller function. Here, what happen after `5 second` script run and when I used `alert()` instead of `window.location.replace()` it works but when I run `window.location.replace()` then It not working. I don't why and where am I doing wrong ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Have you checked if you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I not getting any error @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I am trying to jo with `cron job` but nothing happen @TimBrownlaw

Comment: TRY only location.replace

Answer (score 0):

Your 'if' condition goes wrong and always it won't satisfy all conditions.
Either you can remove `'date.getSeconds() === 1'` OR change `'5000'` to `'1000'` (Runs in each second).

```
<script>
    function checkDate() {
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(date.getDay());
        console.log(date.getHours());
        console.log(date.getMinutes());
        console.log(date.getSeconds());
        if(date.getDay() === 3 && date.getHours() ===13 && date.getMinutes() === 33 ) {
            window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/send_mail_account");
        }
    }

    var dateLoop = setInterval(function() {
        checkDate();
    },5000);
</script>
```

**Set as Cron Job**

Use following command to edit cron tab

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following line to run it on Wednesday 13:33 (Make necessary changes in path)

```
33 13 * * 3 /php.ini-folder-path/php /path/to/codeigniter/root/index.php test send_mail_account
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [location.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) :

```
<script>
    function checkDate() {
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(date.getDay());
        console.log(date.getHours());
        console.log(date.getMinutes());
        console.log(date.getSeconds());
        if(date.getDay() === 3 && date.getHours() ===13 && date.getMinutes() === 33 && date.getSeconds() === 1) {
            location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/send_mail_account");
        }
    }

    var dateLoop = setInterval(function() {
        checkDate();
    },5000);
</script>
```